# Images in UserControl not displaying in window

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, user-controls

I currently have a very simple UserControl that only contains a single image. When I put this UserControl onto another window in the same project, the image no longer appears in the editor, nor does it appear when I run my program. I've looked at every question I can find on this, but I still haven't been able to get this working.

My user control is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.DetailViews.InfoDetails"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="20" d:DesignWidth="20">
<Grid>
    <Image Source="/MyApp;component/Assets/Icon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20"/>
</Grid>
```

I've checked these quesstions:

[Embedded images not showing when in a UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554097/embedded-images-not-showing-when-in-a-usercontrol)

[WPF - UserControl with images not showing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809437/wpf-usercontrol-with-images-not-showing-properly)

[Why are my images not showing up in my UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751406/why-are-my-images-not-showing-up-in-my-usercontrol)

[Image in WPF Button not Visible at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636047/image-in-wpf-button-not-visible-at-runtime)

The thing they seem to all have in common is the build settings for the components. As such, I've set the actual .png *build action* to Content and the *Copy to Output Directory* to Copy always.

The actual UserControl itself has it's *Build Action* set to page (although I've tried setting it to Content or Resource), and is set to Do not copy. These are the same settings as all my other UserControls, and I have no issues with those.

I have the following folder structure:

```
MyApp/MyApp.sln
MyApp/MainWindow.xaml/cs
MyApp/DetailViews/InfoDetails.xaml/cs
MyApp/Assets/Icon.png
```

What have I missed to make the image actually appear on the window?

Thanks.

Comment: if you use this image on an image control(not inside user control) will it load?

Comment: What is the relationship of the `UserControl` to the window in which you're using it? Are they in the same project? Are they in the same folder in the same project? It's not likely anyone will be able to fix your problem without a _complete_ description of how your project(s) is(are) structured, including where and how the resource is being declared.

Comment: As `/MyApp;component/Assets/Icon.png` is a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly), the Build Action of the image file must be `Resource`. Then you would also select `Do not copy`.

Comment: @DarkTemplar, the image loads fine in it's own control on the main window

Comment: @PeterDuniho I've edited the question with those details. This is all in a single project

Comment: Additionally, I would have thought I could put this UserControl on any other Window or UserControl regardless of project layout (In fact, I plan to later). Is this not the case?

Answer (score 4):

Try using full pack URI.

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Assets/Icon.png"
```

For build action you can leave it at "None", but you must select "Copy if newer".

Comment: This is a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly), so the Build Action must of course be `Resource`. Then you would also select `Do not copy`. Besides that, the `pack://application:,,,` prefix isn't necessary in XAML. It is added automatically.

Comment: @Clemens Content File Pack URI also uses the exact same syntax. And also, `pack://application:,,,` prefix denotes absolute path; excluding it means relative path. It's all mentioned in the same URL you provided.

Comment: With the difference that setting the `Content` Build Action just doesn't work with loading image files from Pack URIs. Give it a try.

Comment: @Clemens I tried with `Content` and `Copy if newer`, it worked.

Comment: Ok, I see. My understanding is still that a content file should be loaded by a relative file URL, whereas a Resource file is loaded by a Pack URI.

Comment: For me, using full pack URI doesn't seem to make a difference. Switching settings between None/Content/Resource doesn't help either.